# make linux server allow rsync/scp/sftp but not a terminal login

Tags: linux, ssh, login, rsync

I'd like to configure a linux box (probably an Ubuntu server) so that I can setup users, so that it is possible to upload/download files via rsync/scp/sftp, but it should not be possible to ssh to the machine and get an interactive terminal.

Is this possible? How would I go about configuring that? I know that all I'll need the ssh server to be ON, for rsync/scp/sftp to work, but I guess there should be a way to prevent the direct login.

Comment: I don't think that's possible coz you need a username and pass to use rsync, whoever has the username and pass can login, even if you create an ssh key just for rsync, won't work, would love to be proven wrong though

Comment: It's possible to allow only SFTP with Match User ... / ForceCommand Internal-sftp in `sshd_config`. But to allow several programs i can't help.

Comment: You need a **chroot jail**, SourceForge implements a very good one but I can't find documentation on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the users' shell to [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/). From the manpage:

> rssh - restricted secure shell allowing only scp and/or sftp

Comment: This does not allow rsync, only sftp.

Comment: I can test this later on, however the documentation states:
> It now also includes support for rdist, rsync, and cvs

Comment: I stand corrected: it does support rsync, but by default it is disabled on ubuntu. However, there _is_ a config file /etc/rssh.conf where one can really deeply finetune rssh. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Just calling your attention to this (old!) answer, that rssh has now apparently been  abandoned, and it's being removed from distros. I suggest editing in a note that this is no longer a good solution — or of course do a more extensive update to provide a current solution (I, unfortunately, do not have one to recommend).

Comment: Maybe GNU Rush?  https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/rush/

Answer (score 7):

If you only need to allow rsync, the developers of rsync provide the `rrsync` script to solve your problem.
It is available from here: http://ftp.samba.org/pub/unpacked/rsync/support/rrsync

You just need to add something like this to your `.authorized_keys` file. This example allows read only (`-ro`) access to `/some/directory/`:

```
command="/path/to/rrsync -ro /some/directory/",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAA...
```

A more throughout explanation and example is available here: https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/01/14/restricting-ssh-access-to-rsync/

Update: This is NOT SECURE for write access until this bug is fixed: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11879

As long as this bug persists, please only use rrsync in read only mode (-ro).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo-shell like [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki) and set this for the users you don't want to login directly.

Another possible way is to set the login command in the authorized keys file, but that only works if your users login via SSH-keys and not via password.

Comment: one potential issue with the `authorized_keys` is if the restricted user somehow manages to overwrite the file, to where it no longer imposes that restriction